# Load two different native libraries with the same name in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am working an app that uses 4 native libraries, 2 of which have the same name (something like, lib1, lib2, lib1, lib4) where lib1 are two different libraries sharing the same name.

Is it possible to somehow load all 4 libraries without any  conflict? I am thinking I should move them in two separate folders and load them from there, but not sure how.

Comment: you should refactor the library names

Comment: I do not have the source code. I Only have the *.so files.

Comment: You could add one of the `lib1` libraries as an asset - then when your `Application` is created, copy the asset to your app's file directory (as returned by `getFilesDir()`) and load the copied library with `System.load`.

Comment: An example would be very helpful.